# Working with json.removeWhere() to remove null elements

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to see if this code will work to help process the JSON I have that has a null element in it. I am doing this in DartPad just to see if this will work.

```
var jsonData = {
[
  {
    "addressLine1": "5500 Grand Lake Dr",
    "city": "San Antonio",
    "state": "TX",
    "zipCode": "78244",
    "formattedAddress": "5500 Grand Lake Dr, San Antonio, TX 78244",
    "assessorID": "05076-103-0500",
    "bedrooms": 3,
    "county": "Bexar",
    "legalDescription": "B 5076A BLK 3 LOT 50",
    "squareFootage": 1878,
    "subdivision": "CONV A/S CODE",
    "yearBuilt": 1973,
    "bathrooms": 2,
    "lotSize": 8843,
    "propertyType": "Single Family",
    "lastSaleDate": "2017-10-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "features": null,
    "taxAssessment": {
      "2018": {
        "value": 126510,
        "land": 18760,
        "improvements": 107750
      },
      "2019": {
        "value": 135430,
        "land": 23450,
        "improvements": 111980
      },
      "2020": {
        "value": 142610,
        "land": 23450,
        "improvements": 119160
      },
      "2021": {
        "value": 163440,
        "land": 45050,
        "improvements": 118390
      },
      "2022": {
        "value": 197600,
        "land": 49560,
        "improvements": 148040
      }
    },
    "propertyTaxes": {
      "2019": {
        "total": 2997
      },
      "2021": {
        "total": 3468
      }
    },
    "owner": {
      "names": [
        "MICHEAL ONEAL SMITH"
      ],
      "mailingAddress": {
        "id": "149-Weaver-Blvd,-Weaverville,-NC-28787",
        "addressLine1": "149 Weaver Blvd",
        "city": "Weaverville",
        "state": "NC",
        "zipCode": "28787"
      }
    },
    "id": "5500-Grand-Lake-Dr,-San-Antonio,-TX-78244",
    "longitude": -98.351442,
    "latitude": 29.475962
  }
]
    };

jsonData.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);
```

The error I am getting is on the jsonData.removeWhere() line of code:

> The argument type 'bool Function(List<Map<String, Object?>>, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(List<Map<String, Object?>>)'

I have a null value at the "features:" element of the map.

I tried this on a simple, one-level map and it worked.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: `removeWhere` can have single param(value) on callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enough for your case.

```
for (var element in jsonData) {
  element.first.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `Set<List<Map<String, Object?>>>`, so the `removeWhere` function cannot take `(key, value)` parameters. In other words, you are getting an error because it's a `Set` variable.

In a JSON data, keys must be **unique**.

You can do the following:

1. **Remove the curly braces and use the removeWhere function inside a List.**

```dart
var jsonData = [
  {
   ...
  }

jsonData.forEach((element) => element.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null));
```

Or

2. **You can add a key to the variable and convert it to a Map.**

```dart
var jsonData = {
  null: [ //add here null or something. I recommend use a string value.
    {
     ...
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jsonData.forEach((element) => element.forEach((map) => map.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null)));
```